# androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.IncludedLayouts has protected access in ViewDataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

It was a working project in Android Studio, and today when I opened project it is showing below error for multiple BindingImpl classes. There are two types of error for every BindingImpl class.

The 1st one:

```
error: cannot find symbol
public class ActivityMainBindingImpl extends ActivityMainBinding  {
                                             ^
  symbol: class ActivityMainBinding
```

The 2nd one:

```
error: IncludedLayouts has protected access in ViewDataBinding
    private static final androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.IncludedLayouts sIncludes;
                                                             ^
```

another error in last:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptProdDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

**What I have tried:**

Clean & Rebuild

Invalidate Cache & Restart

Answer (score 17):

The root view of the layout that you're including **must** have an id.

Comment: When this rule added? Can you attach some document link?

Comment: Idk, it happened to me after I've updated gradle and kotlin recently, I just fixed it by trial and error.

Comment: i only needed to add ids to 2 of my layout files to make my project compile and run....weird....i added my `android:id="@+id/root_layout"` on the `<LinearLayout>` direct child of my `<layout>`

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @zOqvxf's answer:

The layout that you are binding should have a root tag `<layout>`. You need to add an id to it, like this:

```
<layout
    ...
    android:id="@+id/layout_root">
```

Comment: i ojnly tried adding my `android:id="@+id/root_layout"` on the `<LinearLayout>` direct child of my `<layout>` to 2 of my files, and it worked for me. very weird..

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one layout file then you have to update both layouts with a layout tag

```
Ex: activity_main.xml,  activity_main.xml landscape
or any other dimensions layout.
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by delete file build, .gradel folder in project and build folder in app folder

Answer (score 0):

solved removing *imports*

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
     </data>
</layout>
```

to this

```
<layout>
        <data>
      
         </data>
    </layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was just a random error, I deleted the layout file, re created it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

For me helped to add explicit version of kotlin std lib, because some dependency could take unexpected version implicitly

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.9.10"
```